# How do I make APT ignore the validity of the Release file?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I'm getting these errors whenever I try to run `apt update`:

> E: Release file for http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 244d 19h 25min 34s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.

I've seen answers mentioning [`-o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/how-to-work-around-release-file-expired-problem-on-a-local-mirror), but that doesn't work as it seems to be only for system dates in the future or expired repos.

**Yes, I know that the system date is wrong.** Back in the past in fact.

How do I make apt use those Release files, ignoring the validity of them or the system date?

Comment: Why can't you just fix your system time?

Comment: i would suggest to change your System time first. else it wount work

Answer (score 1):

Try `-o Acquire::Max-FutureTime=31536000`

31536000 is one year in seconds, which should be enough to accommodate your clock being so far behind.